# A faster way to get frames from video to process with RenderScript

Tags: java, android, video, renderscript

My aim is to read a video from the external memory and process each frame using RenderScript.
I have managed to play this video to a `TextureView`, and use `getBitmap()` to get each frame to be used in an RenderScript allocation to be processed.
The problem is that it is SO SLOW. `getBitmap()` actually copies the BitMap, not reference it.
Can someone please suggest a better way?
Thanks